# Download Excel file with PHP over https

Tags: php, excel, https, download

I am about to take a web application I've been working on live and am now, of course, updating code to make things that worked perfectly on my localhost work on the secure server. One of the tasks this application performs is generating and downloading files. All of the files are being generated and written to the server, but the .xls, .csv, and .json files download with no data even though the data is in the files on the server. The .xml, .zip, and .sql files do download with accurate data. An .xls or .json file that is contained within a .zip file is fine. This problem is not IE specific as I am using Chrome. Also tried Safari with the same results.

Here is what I'm doing to download the Excel:

```
$excel_content = file_get_contents($download_file_name);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding:  binary");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print chr(255).chr(254).mb_convert_encoding($excel_content, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
```

Here is what I'm doing to download the XML:

```
$xml_content = file_get_contents($download_file_name);
header("Content-Type: application/xml");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print $xml_content;
```

Can anyone see why the Excel works on my localhost, but not on my server through https protocol? If it matters, I do have openssl enabled as verified with an info.php file on the server.

Comment: `print chr(255).chr(254).mb_convert_encoding($excel_content, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');` what are you dong here ?

Comment: The print command downloads the excel file. The mb_convert_encoding command (preceded by UTF-16LE byte order mark--chr(255).chr(254)) allows the utf-8 character data from MySQL to display properly in Excel. I found that solution on StackOverflow and it works on my localhost. Getting rid of mb_convert_encoding on my live server made no difference.